# log4j logging implementation at weblogic 12c

Tags: log4j, weblogic12c

I am trying to change the logging implementation that weblogic12c uses to log4j.

I've followed these steps http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLLOG/config_logs.htm#i1014785 and I'v put log4j-1.2.14.jar and wllog4j.jar in DOMAIN_NAME/lib and restarted the domain.

After that I can't see the logging implementation list box that should be shown (http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLACH/taskhelp/logging/SpecifyTheLoggingImplementation.html) in environment -> server -> server -> loggin -> general -> advanced

I must be doing something wrong but I don't know what.

Thanks in advance

Comment: were you able to sort this out?

Comment: Yes, but I solved using log4j in my application, not in Weblogic.
I included log4j as dependency of my application to put the jars inside my ear and declared the weblogic-application.xml this way
<prefer-application-packages>
  <package-name>org.slf4j.*</package-name>
 </prefer-application-packages>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been trying the same thing. I used WL 12.1.2 and the setting described in their documentation exists. Once I moved up to 12.1.3 the Logging Implementation drop down is gone. I found this comment that suggests that weblogic will be removing support for log4j.

https://www.linkedin.com/groups/Is-it-possible-send-weblogic-1320227.S.5926014706660704260

So, it's either a bug or forced removal. You might want to look at trying to configure slf4j in weblogic or just stick with java logging.